# Cassandra Nodetool cleanup - cdc_total_space_in_mb

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

For my multi-node Cassandra cluster, I did some tests and insertion through my python script. I wanted to run `nodetool cleanup` after deleting records from my table but I am encountering this:

> WARN  19:30:08,003 Small cdc volume detected at /cdc_raw; setting
>   cdc_total_space_in_mb to 3556.  You can override this in
>   cassandra.yaml

I believe it is about freeing up or increasing size of CDC logs. How may I solve this problem?

Comment: Why do you have CDC enabled? Do you really need it

Comment: I checked, CDC has been disabled. Puzzled why am I getting this warn.

Comment: data is really deleted during compaction if you removed them with `DELETE` queries. Or you did the `TRUNCATE` on table?

Comment: I did the delete operation.

Comment: and `nodetool cleanup` doesn't remove data that you deleted - it cleanups data after the partitions allocation has changed (by adding/removing nodes)

Comment: The `DELETE` operation is really adding the data to tables, not removing.  If you want to drop all data it's better to execute `TRUNCATE <table>;` & then do `nodetool clearsnapshot` on that table (`TRUNCATE` creates snaphot by default)